# Create a table of values from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a table of herbicide use by applicator and day from user input in Python.  I have a pandas DataFrame with applicator information ('DeviceName') and day of the month ('DAY').  I'm getting the unique day and device name from the DataFrame with:

```
devices = df['DeviceName'].unique()
days = df['DAY'].unique()
```

I'm getting the herbicide usage from the user with:

```
herbicides = []

for device in devices:
    for day in days:
        herbicide = input("How much herbicide did " + str(device) + " use on Day " + str(day) + "?: ")
        herbicides.append(herbicide)
```

If possible, I would like the final output to display the user input like this:

```
   DeviceName          24       25       26       27       28
Applied_AA-19     Input #  Input #  Input #  Input #  Input #
Applied_AA-24     Input #  Input #  Input #  Input #  Input #
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what's the question? If you're looking for help finishing your code, what have you already tried, and where are you stuck? For more tips, see [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: FWIW, you could make an empty df like this: `pd.DataFrame(index=df['DeviceName'].drop_duplicates(), columns=df['DAY'].drop_duplicates())`, then fill in the values using user input.

Comment: BTW, manual string concatenation is annoying. You can use f-strings instead: `input(f"How much herbicide did {device} use on Day {day}?: ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can bootstrap a `d`*ictionnary* with the inputs and pass it to the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) constructor :

```
devices, days = df["DeviceName"].unique(), df["DAY"].unique()

d = {
    device: {
        day: input(f"How much herbicide did {device} use on Day {day}?: ")
        for day in days
    }
    for device in devices
}

out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index").reset_index(names="DeviceName")
```

Output :

```
How much herbicide did Applied_AA-19 use on Day 24?:  1
How much herbicide did Applied_AA-19 use on Day 25?:  2
How much herbicide did Applied_AA-19 use on Day 26?:  3
How much herbicide did Applied_AA-19 use on Day 27?:  4
How much herbicide did Applied_AA-19 use on Day 28?:  5
How much herbicide did Applied_AA-24 use on Day 24?:  6
How much herbicide did Applied_AA-24 use on Day 25?:  7
How much herbicide did Applied_AA-24 use on Day 26?:  8
How much herbicide did Applied_AA-24 use on Day 27?:  9
How much herbicide did Applied_AA-24 use on Day 28?:  10
```

---

```
print(out)

      DeviceName 24 25 26 27  28
0  Applied_AA-19  1  2  3  4   5
1  Applied_AA-24  6  7  8  9  10
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "DeviceName": ["Applied_AA-19", "Applied_AA-24"]*4,
    "DAY": [24, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 28, 28]
})
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your output is exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm getting an error when I run it: TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The `names` parameter of [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) was introduced in [1.5.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#other-enhancements). So you might need to run `pip install --upgrade pandas`. If you can't *upgrade* your pandas version, you can use this `out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index").reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "DeviceName"})`.